# merging two dataframes based upon different time durations

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which have 2 columns; one contains dates and the other contains rainfall quantity. First dataframe's length is from 1/Jan/1960 till 31/Dec/2022 and second's length is 15/Oct/1991 till 31/Dec/2022. I want to merge them in such a manner that the resultant dataframe contains three columns; one with a time series covering the time-slices of both dataframes and the other two columns with rainfall data from both dataframes.
I have tried pd.merge(df1,df2, how='date') but it is not giving desired results. Could you suggest any solution?

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='outer')`?